# In tagged pdf touch up reading order not Shown in Acrobat DC, when the hyperlink present in the Table

Tags: luatex, accessibility, tagged-pdf

I am trying to create a tagged pdf `tagpdf.sty`and `LuaLaTeX`.

The Touch up reading order is not shown in Acrobat DC when the hyperlink is present in the table, but the tag is present in the tagging panel in the pdf (at the same time the touch up reading order is showing in Adobe Acrobat Professional)

There are also multiple unwanted `Path` tags present.

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{}

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tagpdf}
\tagpdfsetup{tabsorder=structure,%
    uncompress,%
    activate-all,%
    interwordspace=true,%
    }


    \usepackage{hyperxmp,array}

    \usepackage[hyperfootnotes=true,unicode,pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 0},breaklinks,bookmarksnumbered,bookmarksopen=true,colorlinks,%
    linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,%
    linktoc=none, pdfview={XYZ null null 1.00}]{hyperref}

    \usepackage{amsmath}


    \begin{document}

    \tagstructbegin{tag=Document}

    \pagestyle{empty}

    \tagstructbegin{tag=P}\tagmcbegin{tag=P}In total, 37.7{\%} of
    respondents (49.4{\%}
    \begin{table}[!h]
    \caption{Logistic Regression Models Showing\protect\hyperlink{tabfootusac153:T0001-fn1}{\textsuperscript{a}}\label{T0001}}
    {\tagstructbegin{tag=Table}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep\fill{\hskip10pt}}p{80pt}p{60pt}p{60pt}@{{\hskip10pt}\extracolsep\fill}}
    \hline
    \tagstructbegin{tag=TBody}%
    \tagstructbegin{tag=TR}%
    \tagstructbegin{tag=TD}\tagmcbegin{tag=TD}%
    Sleep per day (ref: 6\,hours or more)
    \tagmcend\tagstructend
     & &  
    \tagstructend\\
    \tagstructbegin{tag=TR}%
    \tagstructbegin{tag=TD}\tagmcbegin{tag=TD}{\hskip5pt}5\,hours\tagmcend\tagstructend & 
    \tagstructbegin{tag=TD}\tagmcbegin{tag=TD}1.88 (1.20-2.97)\protect\hyperlink{tabfootusac153:T0001-fn2}{\textsuperscript{**}}\tagmcend\tagstructend & 
    \tagstructbegin{tag=TD}\tagmcbegin{tag=TD}0.49 (0.20-1.12)\tagmcend\tagstructend
    \tagstructend
    \\
    \hline\end{tabular*}}
    {\tagstructend\tagstructend
    \tagstructbegin{tag=Note}%
    \tagmcbegin{tag=Note}\protect\hypertarget{tabfootusac153:T0001-fn1}{}$^{\text{a}}$Data in each column are reported from one model that adjusted for all variables in this table.\\
    Abbreviation: AOR\,\ensuremath{=}\,adjusted odds ratio.\\
    \protect\hypertarget{tabfootusac153:T0001-fn2}{}**\textit{P}\,{\textless}\,.01.\\
    \protect\hypertarget{tabfootusac153:T0001-fn3}{}*\textit{P}\,{\textless}\,.05.\tagmcend\tagstructend
    }
    \end{table}

    \tagmcend\tagstructend



    \tagstructend


     \end{document}
```

Comment: Try to make a smaller example.  You should also mention which latex and tagpdf version you use. And why do you set the pdfversion to 1.3??

Comment: The concept of Tagged PDF has been introduced in PDF 1.4, so when you select PDF version 1.3 then you can't really describe it as a Tagged PDF file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I updated a Smaller example in the MWE. I am running the file With LuaLaTeX - Texlive 2021 and pdfmanagement-testphase,sty Released date version 2022-03-17/0.95m  and tagpdf.sty release date version 2022-01-13/0.93

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I removed pdf version in the \DeclareDocumentMetadata{}, the same issue exists. when opening the  file in Acrobat DC, the Touch up reading order is not shown

Comment: Problem solved?

Comment: @MarcelKrüger, yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works for me. It requires a  current `latex-dev` in texlive 2022. You should be careful when tagging the caption: depending on the length it is in a \hbox or not and so can change the behaviour.

```
\DocumentMetadata{testphase=phase-II}

\documentclass{book}

\tagpdfsetup{tabsorder=structure}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{hyperxmp,array}

\usepackage[pdfborderstyle={/S/U/W 0},bookmarksnumbered,bookmarksopen=true,colorlinks,%
    linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,%
    linktoc=none, pdfview={XYZ null null 1.00}]{hyperref}

    \begin{document}

    \pagestyle{empty}

    In total, 37.7{\%} of
    respondents (49.4{\%}
    
    \begin{table}[!h]
    
    \tagstructbegin{tag=Caption}
    \tagmcbegin{tag=Caption}
    \caption{Logistic Regression Models Showing\protect\hyperlink{tabfootusac153:T0001-fn1}{\textsuperscript{a}}\label{T0001}}
    \tagmcend
    \tagstructend
    
    \tagpdfparaOff %no paragraph tagging in the tabular
    \tagstructbegin{tag=Table}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep\fill{\hskip10pt}}p{80pt}p{60pt}p{60pt}@{{\hskip10pt}\extracolsep\fill}}
    \hline
    \tagstructbegin{tag=TBody}%
    \tagstructbegin{tag=TR}%
    \tagstructbegin{tag=TD}\tagmcbegin{tag=TD}%
    Sleep per day (ref: 6\,hours or more)
    \tagmcend\tagstructend
     & &
    \tagstructend\\
    \tagstructbegin{tag=TR}%
    \tagstructbegin{tag=TD}\tagmcbegin{tag=TD}{\hskip5pt}5\,hours\tagmcend\tagstructend &
    \tagstructbegin{tag=TD}\tagmcbegin{tag=TD}1.88 (1.20-2.97)\protect\hyperlink{tabfootusac153:T0001-fn2}{\textsuperscript{**}}\tagmcend\tagstructend &
    \tagstructbegin{tag=TD}\tagmcbegin{tag=TD}0.49 (0.20-1.12)\tagmcend\tagstructend
    \tagstructend
    \\
    \hline\end{tabular*}
    \tagstructend
    \tagstructend
    \par
    
    \tagstructbegin{tag=Note}%
    \tagmcbegin{tag=Note}\protect\hypertarget{tabfootusac153:T0001-fn1}{}$^{\text{a}}$Data in each column are reported from one model that adjusted for all variables in this table.\\
    Abbreviation: AOR\,\ensuremath{=}\,adjusted odds ratio.\\
    \protect\hypertarget{tabfootusac153:T0001-fn2}{}**\textit{P}\,{\textless}\,.01.\\
    \protect\hypertarget{tabfootusac153:T0001-fn3}{}*\textit{P}\,{\textless}\,.05.%
    \tagmcend
    \tagstructend    
        
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]